# Is ARCore will be compatible with Samsung SM-N950W?

Tags: arcore

I have tried Google ARCore for "unsupported" Android devices, and it's just crash ...
Is ARCore will be compatible with Samsung SM-N950W (Note 8)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung recently announced that they will be [supporting ARCore for more of their devices](https://news.samsung.com/global/samsung-shares-vision-for-an-open-and-connected-iot-experience-at-samsung-developer-conference-2017)(scroll to the "Leadership in Augmented Reality" section), which includes the Galaxy Note 8.

The current developer preview, however, is still only [supported by three devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/#supported_devices): Pixel, Pixel XL, and Samsung Galaxy S8.